# Declarative way of specifying units that should run on a CoreOS cluster?

Tags: coreos

Is there a declarative way of specifying what units should be running on a CoreOS cluster and to apply that to an existing CoreOS cluster?  It is undesirable to have to run manual fleetctl commands each time the unit setup changes.

It would be similar to how Ansible makes it possible to declaratively specify what packages should be installed in an server and then apply that to an existing server.

Answer (score 1):

CoreOS machines can be customized by writing a [cloud configuration file](http://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-cloud-config/).

The cloud config is executed upon reboot, so you should expect to reboot the machines in your cluster when you make any changes. However, CoreOS is designed for this kind of ad-hoc rebooting so there shouldn't be any problem.

There are a couple ways to associate cloud configuration data to a VM instance. You can have instances pull cloud configuration files from a read-only storage drive or you can attach the cloud configuration file to a VM instance directly as meta-data if the cloud provider supports this (EC2 and GCE support this style of meta-data tagging)

Comment: Thank you. But if I have a cluster of say 10 machines, should I then arbitrarily reboot one of the machines to apply changes to the units running in the cluster as a whole? This does not seem very elegant.  (Assuming CoreOS can move units started from cloud-config around the cluster, so one cannot expect units to keep running where they were initially started.)

Comment: The cloud-config writes units into the local machine systemd daemon only. The units you define there will not move around onto other machines. If you want this behavior you should load units using fleet. However, from your question it sounds like you want to stick units onto particular machines using cloud-config.